# Can we change the address bar URL after click on anchor tag in my application?

Tags: javascript, html

In my application:
I have like this.
 [my videos](http://youtube/my-technotes1)

after click on my videos  is redirecting to youtube page. now after redirected can change that address url

`youtube/my-technotes1`

to something like `my-tech-videos`.

Is is possible?

Comment: do you want to redirect to another link not the original one given in <a> tag ?

Comment: no same one. bu I want to change the URL in the address bar after we redirected to that

Answer (score -1):

like this?

```js
$("#atag").click(function(){
  $(this).attr("href","http://www.youtube.com")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="atag" target="_blank">my videos</a>
```